# How does Pandas' Correlation Method Handle Non-Numeric Columns?

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, correlation

I'm using Pandas' `.corr()` method to figure out which columns I can eliminate from a large dataset. Some of those columns have non-numeric types.

How does Pandas handle these columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-corr/#:%7E:text=corr()%20is%20used%20to,the%20Dataframe%2C%20it%20is%20ignored.), Pandas will ignore any columns that are non-numeric.

If you want Pandas to perform correlations on your categorical variables you'll have to turn them into dummy variables using `pandas.get_dummies()` ([reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)) or something similar.